# WiFi signal amplifier

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, repeater

I am able to access the Internet over WiFi, but the **signals are too weak**, signal strength remains "fair" or "poor". I cannot relocate, I cannot use hard-wired LAN, nor I can do any kind of modifications on the WiFi router. I can just install a repeater, router, or other device on my place.

What type of device would take BSSID, ESSID, Password, Channel etc., and relay the **amplified signal for me**.  Are there any special characteristics I need to look for in a router that supports this feature?

I have a TP-Link: **TL-WR740N** router.

Comment: SU isnt the site to request hardware recommendations.

Comment: There is now a [site specifically for hardware recommendations](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).  Please see [these guidelines](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-be-high-quality) on what constitutes a good question there.